# ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Data truncated for column 'type'

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, maven

I am new to Hibernate and working on a test project, I have tried a lot of things to get this example working. But I am unsure why it fails, I am aware that the null pointer exception could be because I am trying to getQuestions on Survey but its empty. But I have seen so many tutorials online and followed them and all have the same approach. I have tried recreating the database tables, different versions of hibernate. Nothing has helped me get this resolved. If someone can take a look and guide me would be great help. I would appreciate your feedback. Also if I comment out the question part in Application.java then the survey object gets inserted in the database. I am not sure why the questions fail and don't get insert.Please guide me.

This is my First model class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="question")
public class Question implements java.io.Serializable{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "id")
private Long _id;

@Column(name = "label")
private String _label;

@Column(name="type")
private QuestionType _type;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="survey_id")
private Survey _survey;

public Question() {
}

public Question(final Long id, final String label, final QuestionType type, final Survey survey,final Long surveyId) {
    _id = id;
    _label = label;
    _type = type;
    _survey = survey;

    Assert.notNull(_id, "_id cannot be null");
    Assert.notNull(_label, "_label cannot be null");
    Assert.notNull(_type, "_type cannot be null");
    Assert.notNull(_survey, "_survey cannot be null");
}

public Long getId() {
    return _id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    _id = id;
}


public String getLabel() {
    return _label;
}

public void setLabel(String label) {
    _label = label;
}


public QuestionType getType() {
    return _type;
}

public void setType(QuestionType type) {
    _type = type;
}

public Survey getSurvey() {
    return _survey;
}

public void setSurvey(Survey survey) {
    _survey = survey;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Question [_id=" + _id + ", _label=" + _label + ", _type="
            + _type + "]";
}
```

}

This is my second model class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="survey")
public class Survey implements java.io.Serializable{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "survey_id")
private Long _id;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "_survey")
private List<Question> _questions ;

@Column(name="name")
private String _name;

public Survey() {
    super();
    _questions = new ArrayList<Question>();
}

public Survey(Long id, List<Question> questions, String name) {
    super();
    _id = id;
    _questions = questions;
    _name = name;

    Assert.notNull(_id, "_id cannot be null");
    Assert.notNull(_questions, "_questions cannot be null");
    Assert.notNull(_name, "_name cannot be null");
}

public Long getId() {
    return _id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    _id = id;
}


public List<Question> getQuestions() {
    return _questions;
}

public void setQuestions(List<Question> questions) {
    _questions = questions;
}


public String getName() {
    return _name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    _name = name;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Survey [_id=" + _id + ", _questions=" + _questions + ", _name="
            + _name + "]";
}
```

}

This is my application class:

```
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    System.out.println("Hibernate one to many (Annotation)");
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

    session.beginTransaction();
    Survey survey = new Survey();
    survey.setName("Ice Cream final");
    session.save(survey);


    Question question1 = new Question();
    question1.setLabel("Whats your favorite Ice Cream");
    question1.setType(QuestionType.TEXT);
    question1.setSurvey(survey);
    survey.getQuestions().add(question1); 
    session.save(question1);

    session.getTransaction().commit();
    System.out.println("Done");

 }
```

Hibernate Util Class:

```
public class HibernateUtil {
private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
    try {
        // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
        return new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}

public static void shutdown() {
    // Close caches and connection pools
    getSessionFactory().close();
}
}
```

Hibernate config :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xxxx_survey</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <mapping class="xxxx.Survey" />
    <mapping class="xxxx.Question" />
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Pom.xml has the following dependency:

```
    <!-- MySQL database driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.0-Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>
```

This is the error:

```
Hibernate: insert into survey (name) values (?)
Hibernate: insert into question (label, survey_id, type) values (?, ?, ?)
[main] WARN org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 1265, SQLState: 01000
[main] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Data truncated for column 'type' at row 1
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not insert:    [xxxx.model.Question]
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:140)
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:128)
at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
at   org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:64)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2329)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2836)
at org.hibernate.action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:71)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:268)
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:321)
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:204)
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:130)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:210)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:56)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:195)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:50)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:93)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:705)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:693)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:689)
at xxxx.Application.main(Application.java:38)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Data truncated for column 'type' at row 1
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1055)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3491)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3423)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1936)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2060)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2542)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1734)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2019)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1937)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1922)
at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:94)
at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:57)
... 16 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize `_questions = new ArrayList<Question>();` in your no arg constructor. You are not initializing it anywhere and trying to add a question.

```
public Survey() {
    super();
    _questions = new ArrayList<Question>();
}
```

**EDIT**

MySQL `enum` datatype might not be well supported by hibernate. Try to use a generic approach like, convert the datatype in database to either `varchar` or `int` and use the `@Enumerated` annotation appropriately.

If you can not avoid using enum, then your values of the enum in database and java enum type should exactly match.

Something like,

in db: if you have `type enum('string', 'text')`.
Your java enum should be

```
enum QuestionType {
  string,
  text
}
```

and your mapping should be `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)`.

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply. The null pointer excepection goes away but now I am getting a new error.

Comment: What is the error, and you need to save `survey` after adding the question, that will take care of saving question1 as per you mapping.

Comment: is `QuestionType` an enum? then you need explicitly tell hibernate. Add `@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)` to your `_type` field.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, if I save survey after adding the question, The survey is getting inserted in the database. But question would not.
Question question1 = new Question();
  question1.setLabel("Whats your favorite Ice Cream");
  question1.setType(QuestionType.TEXT);
  question1.setSurvey(survey);
  survey.getQuestions().add(question1); 
  session.save(survey);
  //session.save(question1);
Tried other ways too

Comment: Try the above `@Enumerated` suggestion first and then play around.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, yes its an enum, I added that annotation. But I am still getting the same error. Thank you very much for guiding me.

Comment: What is the data type of `type` in database?

Comment: I refactored the enum to string and commented the annotation just to check if it works. And its getting inserted into both tables, works for me. I don't understand why is it not working with Enum and after having enumeration annotation. The datatype of type is Enum in database. I would really want to use Enum for the Question type. Is there something you can guide me.

Comment: My problem is solved, @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL) was causing the issue I changed it to string @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING).

Comment: Glad that you solved the problem, if the answer is helpful, accept it.

Comment: I want to but I don't have 15 Reputations yet :(

Comment: To up vote you need reputations, to accept (check it) you don't need a reputation

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware about this feature in StackOverflow :)